# Is there a maximum number of projects a service account can have access to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

I am writing an application that does a small job in different projects on gcp. The user adds a service account (from my project) via it's email as a member in the IAM policies to his project. Then he assigns some rights and the application can do its job.

The application could grow in connected projects, so my question is:

is there a maximum number of projects a service account can be a member of?

I read that service accounts shouldn't be created on a "per user" basis and one shouldn't create too many of them. So I don't think I should create a service account per project. On the other hand it seems strange to me to have an account with rights on projects of different customers.

Is there a best practice for handling "multi project" service accounts in a scalable and secure manner?

Answer (score -1):

**"Is there a maximum number of projects a service account can be a
member of?"**

Service accounts are used to call Google APIs of services. Since you must add a service account from another project (call this project B) as a project member (call this project A) in order to assign it roles / permissions in project A, I believe the following limits also apply to your question.

> What is the maximum number of service accounts I can have in a
>   project?
>
> You can create 100 service accounts in a project. Contact your account
>   manager if you need to create more than 100 service accounts in a
>   project.

[Google IAM FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq)

> You can create up to 100 service accounts per project (including the
>   default Compute Engine service account and the App Engine service
>   account) using the IAM API, the GCP console, or the gcloud
>   command-line tool. These default service accounts and the service
>   accounts you explicitly create are the user-managed service accounts.

[Google Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)

**Best practices**

- Restrict who can act as service accounts. Users who are Service Account Users for a service account can indirectly access all the resources the service account has access to. Therefore, be cautious when granting the serviceAccountUser role to a user.
- Grant the service account only the minimum set of permissions required to achieve their goal. Learn about Granting roles to a service account for specific resources.
- Create service accounts for each service with only the permissions required for that service.
- Use the display name of a service account to keep track of the service accounts. When you create a service account, populate its display name with the purpose of the service account.
- Define a naming convention for your service accounts.
- Implement processes to automate the rotation of user-managed service account keys.
- Take advantage of the IAM service account API to implement key rotation.
- Audit service accounts and keys using either the serviceAccount.keys.list() method or the Logs Viewer page in the console.
- Do not delete service accounts that are in use by running instances on Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine.

[Understanding Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply from google docs. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the question is: If I have a project A which creates a service account. To how many projects X can I add that service account as a member? Is there a limit on that? I read something about a limit of 600 refresh tokens on a service account. If this account is a member of 1k+ projects and in 2 mins he authenticates against all these projects to run jobs, will this create problems in authentication etc?

Comment: Google removed the 600 refresh token limit document so I don't know about that point. However, you are misunderstanding what a service account is and how it is used. It is used to issue API calls. This means that the access token would be generated and used for that API call.  The API call would be to a service. That service would be in one project. The token would not be authenticating against 1K+ projects, only with one service at that point in time. Access tokens are valid for one hour (changeable) so I am not sure what caching may be done, but the access token can be reused over and over.

Comment: You should be able to add the same user account (here, the service account) to different projects.Though [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations#cross-project_access_is_possible_but_must_be_explicitly_allowed) help center article is relevant to enterprise-sized organizations, it is still a good reference for your use case. As explained there the service accounts can be granted access to multiple projects, but while providing access to multiple projects keep an eye on the necessary roles/permissions assigned with that account on that project.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the explanation, I am going to initiate only API-Calls with the service account, but probably in many projects. It is just a simple functionality GCP does not provide for which I want to build a service.
In that case, every action done in a project has it's own task in a task-queue which initiates an appengine call, where the service account is used to do the call in project x.
I never said I wanted to use the token for multiple projects. The question was, wheather I have to create multiple service accounts and if there are best practices for multiproject-accounts